# android textview getlayout return null

Tags: android

`textview.getLayout()` returns `null` in `ListViewAdapter.getView()`

I guess I'm calling `textview.getLayout()` too early, before `textview` has been displayed.

When should I call `textview.getLayout()` ?

If I use below code, called `getView()` c​ontinuously

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = textview.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Layout layout = textview.getLayout();
        textview.setText("something")
    }
});
```

and `textview.post(Runnable)` returns `null` too

```
Layout layout = textview.getLayout();
String splitedText = text.substring(0, layout.getLineEnd(maxLines -1)).trim();
splitedText = splitedText + " ..." + moreStr;
```

Using `layout.getLineEnd` produces null pointer exception.

At that stage, the textview is not null, but getLayout() returns null. The textview appears to be initialized.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Context context = parent.getContext();
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(convertView == null)
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    .....

    holder.timeLineContents = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_time_line_contents);
```

Comment: Please show how you have initialised "textview".

Comment: Are you sure textview is correctly initialized? Are you doing this in an activity or a fragment? In an activity I would do this in onCreate method. In a fragment do it in onCreateView method.

Comment: initialised textview like this holder.timeLineReply = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_line_reply_tv);

Comment: have you checked the value of text view using debugger?

Comment: Cleaned up text and code.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation in Android developers,

```
public final Layout getLayout ()

Returns
the Layout that is currently being used to display the text. 
This can be null if the text or width has recently changes.
```

So is there a chance for `getLayout()` to become `null` in case the width of the text changes?

Answer (score 1):

```
holder.timeLineContents.setOnLayoutListener(new OnLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLayoutChanged(SpanTextView view) {
                    SpannableString mLinkableText = null;  
                    InternalMoreSpan span = new InternalMoreSpan(mContext);     
                    if(view.getLineCount() >= 2) {
                        Layout layout = view.getLayout();
                        String splitedText = view.getText().toString().substring(0, layout.getLineEnd(2 - 1)  - 6).trim();
                        splitedText = splitedText + moreStr;
                        mLinkableText = new SpannableString(splitedText);  
                        mLinkableText.setSpan(span, mLinkableText.length()- moreStr.length(), mLinkableText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        view.setText(mLinkableText);
                    }
                }
            });
```

it work well.

Answer (score 1):

call `TextView.onPreDraw()` before `getLayout();`

it makes mLayout in TextView;

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

call this after onStart or onResume

```
if(textView.onPreDraw()) 
        textLayout = textView.getLayout();
```